# Are there surface ravines in deserts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do deserts have ravines, that are open to the surface? I have seen some surface ravines directly at the border of deserts, but never in the middle of a desert.

Comment: Given that sand tends to get stuck until stepped upon, there's a reasonable explanation *if there really are none*: You'd randomly drop tens of blocks because the sand didn't fall down before.

Comment: It falls when you step on it? I thought it needed a block update to fall.

Comment: You're right, sand doesn't fall when you step on it; it needs a block update.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That might be as well. Haven't played in a while. Just remembered something about sand not dropping.

Comment: I have fallen into a ravine in the desert multiple times when exploring.  It was a single block wide hole that somehow was open to the abyss...  I have also found ravines that have sandstone roofs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In world generation logic, desert sand placement comes after digging out ravines. Since deserts come with a solid layer of sandstone underneath them, you will never find an above-ground ravine in a desert.

I'd imagine that this was intentional; realistically you wouldn't ever find above-ground ravines in deserts because they'd simply fill up with sand.

Comment: Then why do you sometimes find caves near the surface where the sand has collapsed into the cave?  Also same with dungeons.

Comment: Ravines ≠ cave systems - they are entirely separate entities and logic in world generation code. Also, Dungeons are one of the last things to be generated in a world.